# Read a Kubernetes Deployment with specific label with python kubernetes client

Tags: python, kubernetes

I am looking for the python Kubernetes client equivalent for

```
kubectl get deploy -n app -l team=blue
```

I'm aware of this function `deployment = api.read_namespaced_deployment(name='foo', namespace='bar')` but how can I have same thing with label?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`read_namespaced_deployment` expects deployment name, which does not make sense of using `label`, you should use [list_namespaced_deployment](https://github.com/kubernetes-client/python/blob/master/kubernetes/docs/AppsV1Api.md#list_namespaced_deployment)

you can use `label_selector`

> `:param str label_selector`: A selector to restrict the list of returned objects by their labels. Defaults to everything.

```py
from kubernetes import client, config
config.load_kube_config()
kube_client = client.AppsV1Api()
resp = kube_client.list_namespaced_deployment(namespace="app", label_selector="team=blue")
for deployment in resp.items:
    print(deployment)
```

to get all label

```
 kubectl get deployment --show-labels
```